# How to provide data from PySide QAbstractItemModel subclass to QML ListView?

Tags: python, qt, pyside, qml

I have an app I'm writing in PySide that has a QML UI. I have subclassed QAbstractListModel in Python:

```
class MyModel(QtCore.QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtCore.QAbstractListModel.__init__(self, parent)
        self._things = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return len(self._things)

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self._things[index.row()]
        return None
```

I provide the model to my QML by doing this in the main script:

```
model = MyModel()
view.rootContext().setContextProperty("mymodel", model)
```

[Qt's docs say](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qdeclarativemodels.html) that the model's role names are used to access the data from QML, and that one can refer to the normal DisplayRole in QML as "display", therefore my QML has a ListView with a simple delegate like this:

```
ListView {
         anchors.fill: parent
         model: mymodel
         delegate: Component { Text { text: display } }
}
```

However, when I do this the result is `file:///foo/bar/main.qml:28: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: display`.

Setting custom role names in the model does not help. Ideas?

Comment: It seems like my model is not being correctly used by the QML, since after I added some logging to rowCount(), I noticed it's not being called :/ That is probably the root cause then. I still don't know why though.

Comment: I removed the parent index validity check from rowCount(), which actually seems to fix dynamic adding of items (beginInserRows(...) ... endInsertRows()). I don't show that bit here because I feel it's irrelevant.

Comment: I have been trying to get this to work too! I have been following the http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qdeclarativemodels.html example, I have not found a pyside equivalent. Have you tried to set the delegate Text { text: modelData } see: http://www.qt.gitorious.org/pyside/pyside-examples/commit/419a83371ba4b4c333559c25bcb7069924b4a227

Comment: yeah, that just causes python to segfault, at least on my Ubuntu Maverick box :p

Comment: I have managed to get it to work without using QAbstractListModel, test are available here: http://www.syrris-support.com/Downloads/JMM/pyside_qml_tests.zip

Comment: There's also this: http://bugs.openbossa.org/show_bug.cgi?id=431 There are attachments with examples that use a list of QObject derivatives as a model. The class declares properties and those are then used in the delegates... but that doesn't work either, at least with Ubuntu's current PySide version (which is out of date, granted).

Comment: I have posted this to the pyside list http://lists.openbossa.org/listinfo/pyside. I attempted to use the examples as part of that bug, with the latest download but that did not work, TypeError: 'notify' is an invalid keyword argument within QtCore.Property

Comment: Heard back from the pyside list via Renato Filho, the GIT HEAD should work.

Comment: Yeah, I managed to work around it the same way as in that openbossa bug. But this case still doesn't work I think.

Comment: This now works with current PySide.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the role names for the model to be able to access the data in QML;

http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/qabstractitemmodel.html#setRoleNames

Comment: That's actually not 100% accurate, you can just use "display" in the delegate to get the data for the display role, at least with PySide 1.0 beta.