# Is there any editor for protobuffer request/response similar to json formatters available online?

Tags: json, xml, editor, protocol-buffers, formatter

I am facing difficulty in creating and editing big protocol buffer request/responses. I found it very easy with JSON, as we have many JSON formatter online ().

Can you please provide information if we have any formatter/editor for protobuf messages, which I couldn't find anywhere?

```
Ex:address{ name:'' sub_address{ field1: 'xx' field2: 'yy'}}
```

Formatted message:

```
address{
   name:''
   sub_address{
      field1: 'xx'
      field2: 'yy'
   }
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this editor](http://freecode.com/projects/protocol-buffers-editor). It's very close to what you need - the only problem it's not online. Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032137/how-to-visualize-data-from-google-protocol-buffer) to the original question with few answers. I guess there is no perfect solution so far. Also [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/protobufeditor/) one.